# SWF doesnt play on RackSpace web server

Tags: iis, flash, mime-types, rackspace-cloud

I have a swf playing video from a rackspace webserver. When I play the swf on a local machine, pulling video frames from the webserver, it works fine. But when I put this swf on the webserver and access it via browser, it doesnt show up.

I checked for swf mime type in IIS, it was enabled.

What could be the issue?

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting up a Cross-domain policy file?

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: Actually the same setup was successfully run on some different webserver without the cross domain policy file. so was wondering

Comment: have you tried using Charles or Fiddler to see what the requests are? It might give you some clues on where the problem is.

Comment: Ok. I will try that and report back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be the mime-type being returned by the web server.  If the web server is returning the wrong mime-type with the SWF file, that would certainly explain the problem.

Check out this page:

http://www.flashcentral.com/Tech/Server/Apache.htm

That page has a good description of what the issue is, and how to fix it.  That's just my first guess though.